# Why does border radius affect svg mask in CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, mask

I have one div with 200px size and a svg rectangular mask with 200px size

- the div in background is just to see how much of div is being masked ornot

when I apply that rectangle as a mask its behavior changes with the border-radius

**case 1 - border radius causes mask to shrink**

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: magenta;
}

#ref {
  background: green;
  mask: url('#mask');
  border-radius: 60px;
}
```

```html
<svg width=0 height=0>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect id="oneRect" fill="#fff" x=0 y=0 width=200 height=200 />

    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
  
  <div></div>
  <div id=ref></div>
```

**case 2 with no border-radius, mask shows the full square**

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: magenta;
}

#ref {
  background: green;
  mask: url('#mask')
}
```

```html
<svg width=0 height=0>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect id="oneRect" fill="#fff" x=0 y=0 width=200 height=200 />

    </mask>
  </defs>
</svg>
  
  <div></div>
  <div id=ref></div>
```

Comment: The issue appears on Chrome, but not on Firefox. A bug perhaps?

Comment: I'm on chrome and both snippets look exactly the same?

Comment: Please try using  maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox"

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this. You should add **border-radius** in div.

```css
div {
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;
            border-radius: 60px;
        }

        #ref {
            background: green;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <div id="ref"></div>
    </div>

    <svg width="0" height="0">
        <defs>
            <mask id="mask">
                <rect id="oneRect" fill="#fff" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
    </svg>
```